# Automating capture of Extent from multiple mxds with multiple dataframes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, error-000210

I want to create a single shapefile from multiple mxd's that have multiple frame sets with different extents in them. I have found/started a script to do this (attached) but can't figure out how to write the captured X&Y Max/Min into the shapefile that is created for this. See output below. I also want it to write the scale and title of the frame as well as the file name of the mxd.

Can you help complete this script?

```
 import arcpy, glob, os from arcpy
 import env from arcpy import mapping
 env.overwriteOutput = True

 path = r"C:\temp" mxdList =
 glob.glob(path + "\*.mxd")

 env.workspace = r"C:\temp\Test.gdb"

 y = 1

 for mxd in mxdList:
     mxd2 = mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
     dataframe = mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd2, "*")[0]
     frameExtent = dataframe.extent
     XMAX = frameExtent.XMax
     XMIN = frameExtent.XMin
     YMAX = frameExtent.YMax
     YMIN = frameExtent.YMin
     pnt1 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMIN)
     pnt2 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMAX)
     pnt3 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMAX)
     pnt4 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMIN)
     array = arcpy.Array()
     array.add(pnt1)
     array.add(pnt2)
     array.add(pnt3)
     array.add(pnt4)
     array.add(pnt1)
     polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
     arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon,
 "Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(y))
     y = y + 1


 list = []

 lstFCs =
 arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Polygon_Extent*")
 for fc in lstFCs:
     list.append(fc)

 arcpy.Merge_management(list, "Extent")

 for item in list:
     arcpy.Delete_management(item)
```

Even with this I get errors...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\2011\Job_031_TownPlanning_SeriesProduction\Working\mxd\extent_creation.py", line 32, in <module>
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon, "Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(y))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 1943, in CopyFeatures
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Polygon_Extent_1
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, the code has been (fixed) and the basic functionality is working. I am still trying to get it to write the mxd file name, extent name and scale but the extent->polygon shp file works when run using IDLE in the same directory as the mxd's.

Would still appreciate help with the above though - I have posted a new question for this at
[How do I insert a DATAFRAME_ELEMENT value into a dynamically generated shapefile containing its extent?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9518/how-do-i-insert-a-dataframe-element-value-into-a-dynamically-generated-shape-file)

(working) CODE
in link above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify you are using shapefiles, you'll need to add shp to the output.

Change this line

```
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon, "Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(y))
```

To this

```
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon, "Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(y) + ".shp")
```

Also, change this line

```
    arcpy.Merge_management(list, "Extent")
```

To this

```
    arcpy.Merge_management(list, "Extent.shp")
```

Comment: Thanks...I made these changes and now get the following. ...

Answer (score -1):

npeihl, Thanks for your input...I now get.

> > > P:\2011\Job_031_TownPlanning_SeriesProduction\Working\mxd\1
> > >       
> > >       
> > >       219157.947938379 8072842.27839025 377350.947938381 8205437.27839025 NaN NaN NaN NaN
> > >       377350.947938 219157.947938
> > >       8205437.27839 8072842.27839
> > >       219157.947938379 8072842.27839025 NaN NaN 219157.947938379 8205437.27839025 NaN NaN
> > >       377350.947938381 8205437.27839025 NaN NaN 377350.947938381 8072842.27839025 NaN NaN
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 322, in RunScript
> > >           debugger.run(codeObject, **main**._*dict*_, start_stepping=0)
> > >         File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger__init__.py", line 60, in run
> > >           _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
> > >         File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 655, in run
> > >           exec cmd in globals, locals
> > >         File "P:\2011\Job_031_TownPlanning_SeriesProduction\Working\mxd\1\extent_creation2.py", line 40, in 
> > >           TempFile = open(polygon, "Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(y)) # open file
> > >       TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Polygon found