# ArcGIS Extract Data Tool

Tags: arcpy

I am lookinig for a way to use an AOI to search and extract data from the data drive on the network at work. So, for example, I have folders of elevation data. Instead of sorthing through each folder and subfolder, I can just use an AOI and it will only give me back the data I need. The Extract Data tool in in the Server Tools toolbox is kind of what I am looking for, but it only performs the extraction on data within the table of contents.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use lots of iteration.  This is the general logic as semi-psuedocode that you can follow:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = ROOT = r'some\root\path'

# loop thu workspaces (arcpy.ListWorkspaces())
# for ws in arcpy.ListWorkpaces:
#   if is ANY type of gdb:
#   arcpy.env.workspace = gdb = os.path.join(ROOT, ws)
#       # loop thru root of gdb
#       for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
#           arcpy.analysis.Clip <-- if feature class
#       for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
#           arcpy.management.Clip <--  raster
#       loop thru feature data sets
#       for fd in arcpy.ListDatasets('*', 'Feature'):
#           set workspace to feature dataset
#           #arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(ROOT, ws, fd)
#           #loop through feature classes
#           for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
#               arcpy.analysis.Clip <-- if feature class
#           for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
#               arcpy.management.Clip <--  raster

#   elif workspace is folder:
#       set workspace to folder
#       #loop through feature classes
#       for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
#           arcpy.analysis.Clip <-- if shapfile
#       for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
#           arcpy.management.Clip <--  raster
#   # loop thru subfolders?  os.walk
```

You would also need to decide how to handle subfolders.  It may also be worth looking into [arcpy.da.Walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000)

Answer (score 1):

First consideration: how do you want to create the AOI? You could easily use the current extent of the data frame if this tool is to be run from arcmap.  [This](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/creating-extent-polygons-using-arcpy.html) or [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/automating-capture-of-extent-from-multiple-mxds-with-multiple-dataframes) may be useful.  Or, I believe, with a python toolbox you could create a polygon with a few clicks.

At any rate, once you have the polygon as a feature (I would suggest creating an in_memory feature class) I would say [arcpy.da.Walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000) is the best way way to go.  Use it like this:

```
import arcpy
import os

topdir = r"path/to/root/folder"

for path, dirs, files in arcpy.da.Walk(topdir):
    for d in dirs:

        arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(path,d)

        for ws in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
            arcpy.env.workspace = ws

            for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():                    
                # do raster stuff
            for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
                # do vector stuff
```

This *should* collect everything you need.  You may want to use the [arcpyDescribe()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Describe/018v00000066000000/) function on the rasters and fcs to get more information about them before you clip or extract them.  It looks like there are filters you can use with arcpy.da.Walk, I just don't have experience with them.